# I accidentally closed the window for the verfication code

Tags: ubuntu-one

I wanted to create an account for Ubuntu One, but I got impatient when the email with the verification code didn't arrive... I thought I might have typed the wrong address, closed the window and tried again. it told me the address already existed and I just got the code. But since I closed the window I missed it. Is there any way to recover the code?

Comment: You try to check your browser's history and checked the recently closed windows.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to log in on https://login.ubuntu.com/ using the username/password you used to create the account, and enter the verification code somewhere on that site.

If you are unable to do so, you should contact https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ for support.